# Python reads only one column from my CSV file

Tags: python, database, csv, jupyter-notebook, multiple-columns

first post here.

I am very new to programmation, sorry if it is confused.
I made a database by collecting multiple different data online. All these data are in one xlsx file (each data a column), that I converted in csv afterwards because my teacher only showed us how to use csv file in Python.

I installed pandas and make it read my csv file, but it seems it doesnt understand that I have multiple columns, it reads one column. Thus, I can't get the info on each data (and so i can't transform the data).

I tried df.info() and df.info(verbose=True, show_counts=True) but it makes the same thing
len(df.columns) = 1 which proves it doesnt see that each data has its own column
len(df) = 1923, which is right

I was expecting that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEFSa.jpg (different project, not the same database)
database used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8GUB.jpg

And I have that instead : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNCTH.jpg
database used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECboh.jpg

idk, it looks pretty similar, why doesn't work :((

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add the code you got so far, someone will help based on that... (Not as a picture!)

Comment: It looks like the separator in your csv file is ";" instead of "," which is default for pandas -- try using the read_csv function with parameter sep = ';'

Comment: yessss, thanks mate!! it worked with sep = ';' in the read_csv line.

sorry for the screens btw, i'll copy & paste the code next time !!